# How to display the number of child data in Firebase Realtime Database (v9) using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to display (onclick) inside an input field the number of child data from my database. The ID of the input field is "output1". This is the code I tried in getting the number of children:

JS code:

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(){             
    const dbRef = ref(database, 'Users');

    onValue(dbRef,(snapshot) => {

        var output1 = snapshot.numChildren();
        document.getElementById('output1').value = output1;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [`DataSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.datasnapshot) in the v9 SDK doesn't have a `numChildren` method anymore. Instead, you can use its `size` property to get the number of child nodes.

Comment: How can I use the size property to get the total number of child nodes? I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: You should be able to do `var output1 = snapshot.size;` Is that not working for you?